# Pass container object in XSLTProcessor

Tags: php, symfony, xslt, xslt-1.0

is there any way to pass or bind Container object and call Service object's method in XSLTProcessor. some thing like.

```
XSLTProcessor::registerFunction(); //in php file.
```

in xsltStylesheet

`<xslt:value-of select="php:function('serviceobject::serviceObjectMethod',string($xsltProcessingVariable))"/>`

Answer (score 2):

In "normal" php code you can do something like

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public function __construct($prefix) {
        $this->prefix = $prefix;
    }

    public function myMethod($id) {
        return sprintf('%s#%s', $this->prefix, $id);
    }
}

$fooA = new Foo('A');
$fooB = new Foo('B');

echo call_user_func_array( array($fooA, 'myMethod'), array('id1') ), "\r\n";
echo call_user_func_array( array($fooB, 'myMethod'), array('id1') ), "\r\n";
```

i.e. instead of giving [`call_user_func_array`](http://docs.php.net/call_user_func_array) just the name of the function you pass an `array($obj, 'methodName')` to invoke an instance method.
Unfortunatley that doesn't seem to work with `php:function(...)` and I haven't found another easy/clean way to do it.
But you could register your objects in a lookup table string_id->object and then use something like

```
select="php:function('invoke', 'obj1', 'myMethod', string(@param1), string(@param2))"
```

in your stylesheet. `function invoke($objectId, $methodName)` now has to find the object that has been registered under `$objectId` and then invoke the method like in the previous example.
[func_get_args()](http://docs.php.net/func_get_args) lets you retrieve all parameters passed to a function, even those that are not declared in the function signature. Cut off the first two elements (i.e. $objectId and $methodName) and pass the remaining array as arguments to call_user_func_array.

self-contained example:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public function __construct($prefix) {
        $this->prefix = $prefix;
    }

    public function myMethod($id) {
        return sprintf('%s#%s', $this->prefix, $id);
    }
}

function invoke($objectId, $methodname)
{
    static $lookup = array();

    $args = func_get_args();
    if ( is_null($methodname) ) {
        $lookup[$objectId] = $args[2];
    }
    else {
        $args = array_slice($args, 2);
        return call_user_func_array( array($lookup[$objectId], $methodname), $args);
    }
}

// second parameter null -> register object
// sorry, it's just a quick hack
// don't do this in production code, no one will remember after two weeks
invoke('obj1', null, new Foo('A'));
invoke('obj2', null, new Foo('B'));

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->registerPHPFunctions();
$proc->importStyleSheet(new SimpleXMLElement( style() ));
echo $proc->transformToXML(new SimpleXMLElement( document() ));

function document() {
    return <<<EOB
<doc>
    <element id="id1" />
    <element id="id2" />
</doc>
EOB;
}

function style() {
    return <<<EOB
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="element">
        Obj1-<xsl:value-of select="php:function('invoke', 'obj1', 'myMethod', string(@id))"/>
        |||
        Obj2-<xsl:value-of select="php:function('invoke', 'obj2', 'myMethod', string(@id))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOB;
}
```

prints

```
    Obj1-A#id1
    |||
    Obj2-B#id1

    Obj1-A#id2
    |||
    Obj2-B#id2
```

btw: don't implement your invoke() function like I did in this example. I just failed to come up with a better way to implement a register()/invoke() functionality for this quick example ;-)